# Selecting an item from Drop Down list in Espresso

Tags: android-espresso, android-adapterview

I am trying to write the Espresso test that will navigate to search, type 2 letters to get incremental search and tap on 2nd item on the list.

The results are displayed in adapter.

Of course, I do the first part well, but when I need to click on the item in the list, there is a problem.

I already tried something like

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.searchContainer)).atPosition(1).perform(click())
```

and

```
onData(withChild(withText("Some Search"))).atPosition(1).perform(click())
```

(where Some Search is the complete text of the result)

and

```
onData(withId(android.R.id.text1)).atPosition(1).perform(click())
```

(where text1 is id of the result field)

```
    @Test
    fun searchForSandwich() {

        onView(withId(R.id.textSearch)).perform(typeText("ha"))

        onData(withChild(withText("Ham Sandwich"))).atPosition(1).perform(click())
```

It should click the result and open new screen / activity and I will do my assertion there.

Currently, I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
(is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView and is displayed on the screen to the user)
Target view: "ce{id=-1, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@4d102dd, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}"
```

Any suggestions, It's driving me crazy... Thanks :)

Comment: I also tried something like:

```
onData(allOf(`is`(instanceOf(String::class.java)), `is`("Ham Sandwich"))).perform(click())
```

And it didn't work, which is strange, because it is an exact hard coded result...

Answer (score 0):

I need to see the view to make sure but %99 percent you don't need to use onData and can just get away with onView(withText(containsString(yourSearchFilter))).perform(click()).

There is also probably a withSubstring(text) which corresponds to withText(containsString(text))

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with text: a string containing "SEARCH TERM"
If the target view is not part of the view hierarchy, you may need to use Espresso.onData to load it from one of the following AdapterViews:com.google.maps....